# How to .bat launch a vnc session in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vnc

I have a specific vnc session I want to start up:

```
myhost: 5000
Password: *()BS^Y9hub)GS*^&Dt
```

I am using the standalone `VNCViewer-5.x.x.exe` file right now to start it. `vncviewer` command does not exist.

Is there a way for me to create a batch file such that I can run to start up the VNC session without going through the GUI?

Comment: [vncviewer man page](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.3/reference/vncviewer.html) tells you what you need to know.

Comment: Be careful saving your password in a .bat, this is not good practice. Most versions of VNC include an address book, which allow you to manage saved connections, along with shortcuts to these connections (and even allow you to store the password).

Comment: If someone can provide an answer, something that can be put into a bat file, that would help. @root Am looking for answer that would be ideal for what I am trying to do. I want to stop manually opening exe file, selecting the specific hostname/port, then entering my password everytime I need to use VNC.

Comment: @sdfds My suggestion to use VNC's build in shortcut feature satisfies this need. It creates a `.vnc` file with the saved host-address and password, simply double clicking the icon will launch the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `cd` into the directory in which you have the `vncviewer` application. For example:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer"
```

and you can do `vncviewer.exe -help`. This should solve your issue with the command.